# jQuery rewrite copied text before pasting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery script that copies a text from a html element and pastes it into a input fields value.

```
var txt=$('div').text();
$('#name').val(txt);
```

The problem I have is that I need to rewrite some of the text that has been copied before adding it to the input field.

When the text is copied and pasted it shows '%40' I need to rewrite '%40' and make it an '@' symbol.

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the unescape function: `unescape(txt)`
For example: `unescape("email%40example%2ecom")` returns "email@example.com"